# ComponentDidMount() not working

Tags: reactjs, matter.js

I am making a game using matter.js in reactjs.

I am suffering a problem where I cannot return anything in the render().

Probably this is because matter.js has its own renderer.

So I did not retun anytihng into the render section.

If i don't return anything in the render section componentDidMount do not run.

I am Unable to run componentDidMount() and i cannot call any function even though i bind it.

I am calling a start_game() function to start game but any other function that I call within start_game() an error comes which says that no such function exist even though I have declared it within the class.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Matter from 'matter-js';
const World = Matter.World;
const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const Renderer = Matter.Render;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const Events = Matter.Events;
const Mouse = Matter.Mouse;
const MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
const Body = Matter.Body;

class Walley extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.world = World;
        this.bodies = Bodies;
        this.engine = Engine.create(
            {
                options:
                    {
                        gravity: { x: 0, y: 0,}
                    }
            });
        this.renderer = Renderer.create(
            {   element: document.getElementById('root'),
                engine: this.engine,
                options:
                    {
                        width: window.innerWidth,
                        height: window.innerHeight,
                        background: 'black',
                        wireframes: false,
                    }
            });

         this.state = {
            play_game: false,
            score:0,
                };


        this.play_game=this.play_game.bind(this);
    }

    play_game(){

            this.setState
            ({
                score: 50,
            });

        }

    startGame()
    {

        console.log(this.state.play_game);
        //don't know how here the value of play_game is set to true even it was false in componentWillMount()
        if(this.state.play_game){
            this.play_game();
         //unable to access play_game
        }

    }
    componentWillMount()
    {
        if (confirm("You want to start game?"))
        {   
            this.setState({play_game: true});
        }
        console.log(this.state.play_game);
        //even though play_game is set true above yet output at this console.log remains false
    }

    render()
    {
        if(this.state.play_game)
        this.startGame();
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        //unable to access
        console.log('Did Mount');
    }
}

export default Walley;
```

Comment: a React component must always return something through `render()`. `startGame` should be called in `componentDidMount` because DOM is required. I suggest you to learn [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: i know that already. I did not return anything intensionally because already matter.js has a renderer. I cannot create and return one of my own.

Comment: If your component doesn't have anything to be rendered, the component can't be mount, and therefore won't evoke componentDidMount.
As a design perspective, you might want to create a game loop to check when to startGame, or create some actions and dispatcher to startGame accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`render` needs to be a pure function, meaning you should not call `startGame` from inside `render`. I think you want something closer to this:

```
// remove this
// componentWillMount() {}

componentDidMount() {
  if (confirm("You want to start game?")) {   
    this.setState({play_game: true}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.play_game);
    });
    startGame();
  }
}

render() {
  // eventually you will want to return a div where you can put your matter.js output
  return null;
}
```